# Json.NET Not Respecting PreserveReferencesHandling on Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a list of **Team** that I am trying to deserialise.

```
class Team  
{
    public string TeamName {get; set;};
    private List<FootballPlayer> _fPlayers = new List<FootballPlayer>();
    public List<FootballPlayer> FPlayers
    {
        get => _fPlaters;
    }
}

class FootballPlayer
{
    private Team _team;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Team Team 
    {
        get => _team;
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public FootballPlayer(Team team)
    {
        _team = team;
    }
}
```

I have the following JSON settings:

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
```

When I look at the **serialised output**, it appears **correct**, and the references between nodes are properly represented.

```
  {
      "$id": "1",
      "TeamName": "Test",
      "FPlayers": [
      {
        "$id": "2",
        "Team": {
          "$ref": "1"
        },
        "Name": "Leo Messi"
      }
    ]
  }
```

When the data is **deserialised**, the property "Team" in the player "Leo Messi" is **null**.

How can I deserialise this JSON in such a way that the property "Team" of "Leo Messi" is not null?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Team>>(JsonString, serializerSettings);
```

Comment: this json is an object not an array, why you use `List<Team>`?

Comment: @Sajid I trimmed the json for readability

Comment: `PreserveReferencesHandling` is documented to not work with parameterized constructors, see [Newtonsoft.Json issue with deserialising relational model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61212033/3744182), of which I believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: @dbc thanks you! If a want deserialise a field that is readonly how can i do?